# Bootstrap hamburger menu not expanding

Tags: jquery, css, django, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm getting back into web development using Django after quite some time and I've got the seemingly common issue of my bootstrap hamburger menu not expanding in my nav bar. It's driving me absolutely nuts. It was working fine, then I did some refactoring and it's no longer working. I can't seem to find the issue, I've tried switching out the bootstrap links with ones found here, confirming the ID matches etc but no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Scripts from Bootstrap:

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Title</title>
    ...
            <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
            <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="bootstrap-override-customnav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home'%}">
        <img src="{% static 'images/logo.png'%}" alt="" width="40" height="40">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home'%}">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'interactivequery'%}">Interactive Query Tool</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'education'%}">Education</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about'%}">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Diamond ID" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success customnavbtn" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
nav .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
color:#3282b8;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}

nav .container-fluid .navbar-brand:hover {
color:#3282b8;
}

nav .d-flex .customnavbtn {
    background-color:#1b262c;
    color:#F2F2F2;
    border-color:#F2F2F2;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

nav .d-flex .customnavbtn:hover{
    background-color:#bbe1fa;
    color:#1b262c;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
 
nav .d-flex .customnavbtn:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color:#bbe1fa;
    color:#1b262c;
    border-color: #F2F2F2;
}

#bootstrap-override-customnav{
    background:#1b262c;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color:#F2F2F2;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    color:#bbe1fa;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:focus {
    color:#bbe1fa;
    box-shadow: none;

}
```

Comment: Is it because of using the CSS for bootstrap 5 but using bootstrap 4.3.1 for your JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you're using the new v5 version of bootstrap while using the old javascript file v4.3.1. bootstrap no longer needs jQuery to work
Try implementing this instead

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Replacing my 3 script tags at the bottom of my <body> with this one did the trick. Should I have left the popper.js in there, or does this take care of that as well? Thanks!

Comment: it does take care of it. the script I mentioned is a bundle containing both the bootstrap and popper js files

Comment: Searched for hours over several days before I found this!  The following link points to a more up to date version of the bootstrap js (answer has a beta version) `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`